# Trying to set Core Data Relationships causing crash

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-data

I have a few entities, one named "List" and one named "Task". The both have multiple properties and only 1 relationship. The list property has a to-many relationship called hasTasks, whose destination is task.

This is the Task.h file that is generated for me.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

@class Task;

@interface List : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * number;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * tasks;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * totalTime;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *hasTasks;
@end

@interface List (CoreDataGeneratedAccessors)

- (void)addHasTasksObject:(Task *)value;
- (void)removeHasTasksObject:(Task *)value;
- (void)addHasTasks:(NSSet *)values;
- (void)removeHasTasks:(NSSet *)values;

@end
```

Whenever I run a line of code such as :

```
[self.list addHasTasksObject:task];
```

it crashes my app without any error message. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is `Task` set up to a have relationship to `List`? Also, what happens if you simply do `task.list = list`?

Comment: Yes Task is set up to have a relationship to List, but trying to set that relationship also crashes the app. Doing task.list = list will not work since list is not a property or the name of a relationship .

Comment: Add an exception Breakpoint for to know the exception message

Comment: I did, and it just tells me the breakpoint is at the line of code [self.list addHasTasksObject:task]; and there is no error printed out in the console.

Comment: Make sure that both `self.list` and `task` are valid objects by NSLogging them. Also check whether they both have same `context` property.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem and I fixed it in the .xcdatamodeld file.  I had accidentally selected the ordered arrangement checkbox for a relationship without re-generating the NSManagedObject classes. Unchecking this box and re-building solved this problem for me.  If you are still having a problem, try re-generating your NSManagedObject classes.